# Как в sql сопоставить таблицу с несколькими колонками?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Допустим у меня есть 2 таких таблицы. Поля risk1_id, risk2_id, risk3_id связаны (FOREIGN KEY) с полем id из (первая таблицы) допустим это таблица risks.
[image: таблица risks]
[image: таблица с полями risk1_id , risk2_id, risk3_id]

И нужно связать таблицы по полям id , risk1_id , risk2_id, risk3_id. Да знаю что по хорошему нужна еще одна таблица

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, что тебе нужно составить 3 отдельных запроса и объединить их через `UNION`

```
JOIN по risk1_id
UNION
JOIN по risk2_id
UNION
JOIN по risk3_id
```